# Did I covert my appender correctly from log4j to log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am converting some log4j property files to log4j2 and I would like to know if I am doing it correctly or not.

The old log4j:

```
log4j.appender.errortail=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errortail.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.errortail.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.errortail.File=${catalina.base}/log/catalina_error.log
log4j.appender.errortail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errortail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1} - %m%n

...

log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stderr, errortail
```

My conversion to log4j2:

```
appender.errortail.type = RollingFile
appender.errortail.name = errortail
# Set max file size to 50MB
appender.errortail.policies.type = Policies
appender.errortail.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errortail.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.errortail.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.errortail.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errortail.policies.size.size = 50MB
# Set max backup index to 10
appender.errortail.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.errortail.strategy.max = 10
appender.errortail.fileName = ${catalina.base}/log/catalina_error.log
appender.errortail.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.errortail.layout.pattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1} - %m%n

...

rootLogger.level = ERROR
rootLogger.appenderRef.stderr.ref  = stderr
rootLogger.appenderRef.errortail.ref  = errortail
```

Is this correct? I don't think I did the multiple appender thing correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 2.7, which was just released, contains an experimental tool to convert typical log4j 1.x properties files to Log4j 2. You could try that and compare what it generates with what you have created.  See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/apidocs/index.html for information (which is admittedly minimal at the moment) on how to use it. The work is being captured under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1525.